# Finding a matching ID using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a group of hidden divs all with the same class but with unique automatically generated IDs.  I also have thumbnails which have the exact same IDs as the hidden divs.

When a thumbnail is clicked it's ID is stored in the variable `clickedId` like this:

`var clickedId = $(this).attr("id");`

but what I can't figure out is how to find the hidden div with that particular ID so that it can be shown with that same click.

This is the relevant HTML showing the divs to be unhidden.

```
<div id="projectHolder">
   <div class="project-content" id="project-<?php echo $post->post_name;?>">                                
   <p>Div content</p>
   </div>

   <div class="project-content" id="project-<?php echo $post->post_name;?>">                                
   <p>Div content</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

I've tried variations on this but they are mainly my guesses:

```
$('.project-content').find().each(function(){
if ($this.is(clickedId)).fadeIn(); 
});
```

Any suggestions to point me in the right direction?

Comment: `ID`'s by their very definition, are unique. You cannot have multiple items with the same ID on a single page. Use classes.

Comment: Thanks Ahren, I'll change to classes but I still need help matching the classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but should get you going.

```
$('#projectHolder').children("#" + clickedId).fadeIn();
```

Also, as has been said, consider switching to classes so you don't have duplicate Ids on the page.

Comment: Thank you Ryan, this was the one - updated to classes and it works nicely.

Answer (score 4):

If you used classes you could do something like:

```
$(".project-content").click(function(){
  $('.project-content').not(this).fadeToggle();
});
```

Comment: Surely you can do better than re-querying the entire DOM for `.project-content` elements.

Comment: To quote myself: *something like*

Comment: Thanks Ahren, I didn't know about not(this)

Comment: @maikunari - you're welcome. You can read more about it here: http://api.jquery.com/not/

Answer (score 3):

Use an [HTML5 `data-*` attribute](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) on the thumbnail which contains the ID (or a selector) for the  element that should be correspondingly displayed when the thumbnail is clicked.

```
<div data-open-target="#foo">...</div>
```

Then:

```
var clicked = $(this).data('open-target');
// later
$(clicked).fadeIn();
```

Comment: This looks great but not sure how to generate the data attribute on the wordpress posts - but the answer below worked for me.